# Azure ML - AKS Service deployment unable to handle concurrent requests despite auto scaling enabled

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have deployed around 23 models (amounting to 1.57 GB) in a Azure ML workspace using Azure Kubernetes Service. For the AKS cluster, I have used 3 D8sv3 nodes, and enabled cluster auto scaling for the cluster up to 6 nodes.
The AksWebService is configured with 4.4 cores, 16 GB memory. I have enabled pod auto scaling for the Web service, having set autoscale_max_replicas at 40:

```
aks_config = AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores = 4.4, memory_gb = 16, autoscale_enabled = True,
                                            description = 'TEST - Configuration for Kubernetes Compute Target',
                                            enable_app_insights = True, max_request_wait_time = 25000,
                                            autoscale_target_utilization = 0.6, autoscale_max_replicas = 40)
```

I tried running load tests with 10 concurrent users (using JMeter). And I monitored the cluster application insights:
[image]
[image]

I can see the nodes and pods scaling. However, there is no spike in CPU/memory utilization. For 10 concurrent requests, only 5 to 6 requests pass, the rest fail. When I send an individual request to the deployed endpoint, the response is generated in 7 to 9 seconds. However, in the load test logs, there are plenty requests taking more than 15 seconds to generate a response. And the requests taking more than 25 seconds, fail with status code 503. I increased the `max_request_wait_time` due to this reason, however, I don't understand why it would take so much time despite such amount of compute, and the dashboard shows that memory isn't even 30% utilized. Should I be changing the `replica_max_concurrent_requests` param? Or should I be increasing the `autoscale_max_replicas` even more? Concurrent requests load may sometimes reach 100 in production, is there any solution to this?

Will be grateful for any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a good solution? Dealing with a similar use case. Thanks!

Comment: @Will I was under utilizing the individual replicas. Each replica handles a single request. I set autoscale_target_utilization = 0.7, autoscale_min_replicas = 140, and autoscale_max_replicas = 180. This was suitable for the production load I had predicted. Also since each replica was handling one request only, cpu_cores = 1.0, memory_gb = 3.8